# How do I transform &str to ~str in Rust?

Tags: string, pointers, rust, rust-obsolete

This is for the current 0.6 Rust trunk by the way, not sure the exact commit.

Let's say I want to for each over some strings, and my closure takes a borrowed string pointer argument (&str). I want my closure to add its argument to an owned vector of owned strings ~[~str] to be returned. My understanding of Rust is weak, but I think that strings are a special case where you can't dereference them with * right? How do I get my strings from &str into the vector's push method which takes a ~str?

Here's some code that doesn't compile

```
fn read_all_lines() -> ~[~str] {
    let mut result = ~[];
    let reader = io::stdin();
    let util = @reader as @io::ReaderUtil;
    for util.each_line |line| {
        result.push(line);
    }
    result
}
```

It doesn't compile because it's inferring result's type to be [&str] since that's what I'm pushing onto it. Not to mention its lifetime will be wrong since I'm adding a shorter-lived variable to it.

I realize I could use ReaderUtil's read_line() method which returns a ~str. But this is just an example.

So, how do I get an owned string from a borrowed string? Or am I totally misunderstanding.

Comment: This is less relevant now given that Rust is at 1.X. (Rust 1.X uses `String` and `&str`, not `~str`) So, it would be helpful to label this as pre-Rust 1.0. My hope is that search engine relevance could be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: I could be out of line here, but I have voted to close this question as it does not apply to current Rust syntax, which does not include ~

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should call the StrSlice trait's method, to_owned, as in:

```
fn read_all_lines() -> ~[~str] {
    let mut result = ~[];
    let reader = io::stdin();
    let util = @reader as @io::ReaderUtil;
    for util.each_line |line| {
        result.push(line.to_owned());
    }
    result
}
```

StrSlice trait docs are here:

http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/core/str.html#trait-strslice

Comment: 2013 Rust looks *very* different from modern Rust.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

For one, it doesn't work semantically: a `~str` promises that only *one thing owns it at a time*.  But a `&str` is borrowed, so what happens to the place you borrowed from?  It has no way of knowing that you're trying to steal away its only reference, and it would be pretty rude to trash the caller's data out from under it besides.

For another, it doesn't work logically: `~`-pointers and `@`-pointers are allocated in completely different heaps, and a `&` doesn't know *which* heap, so it can't be converted to `~` and still guarantee that the underlying data lives in the right place.

So you can either use `read_line` or make a copy, which I'm...  not quite sure how to do  :)

I do wonder why the API is like this, when `&` is the most restricted of the pointers.  `~` should work just as well here; it's not like the iterated strings already exist somewhere else and *need* to be borrowed.

Answer (score 4):

At first I thought it was possible to use `copy line` to create owning pointer from the borrowed pointer to the string but this apparently copies burrowed pointer.

So I found `str::from_slice(s: &str) -> ~str`. This is probably what you need.

Comment: I tried "copy line" too. It seemed weird to me that they'd provide a way to read all the lines, but it gives you borrowed pointers and you can't copy them. It seems str::from_slice uses an unsafe raw byte copy.

Comment: Yes, it makes copy of the string. Just what you need to create owning pointer. I don't think it matters if there is unsafe call beneath the function if it works as intended. Anyway we have unsafe operations on the deepest level.

Comment: @DmitryBelyaev Thanks. I was more interested how it was implemented to see if there was a recommended way to copy borrowed strings.